# is it possible to rollback table even if table doesn't have update and delete permission?

Tags: sql, sql-server, commit, rollback

Can i Roalback table if table doesn't have update or delete permission?

Comment: Tables have no permissons, users have.

Answer (score 2):

Anything you *do* have permission to do, you also have "permission" to undo via a rollback.

The rollback/undo process isn't really covered by the permissions system, so the above is more a viewpoint on the process than something specifically documented.

Answer (score 0):

Rollback is a specific mechanism used in transactions, typically transactions that modify tables.

There are (typically) three ways you can modify a table in a transaction, `insert`, `update`, and `delete`.  So, you can rollback a transaction if you have `insert` permission, but not `update` or `delete` permission.

I don't think this is what you mean.  I think the answer is that you cannot even start to run a transaction if you don't have the appropriate permissions.  So, rolling back a transaction that you can't execute is not possible, because you can't even start the transaction.

Comment: I think I get what you're trying to say here but something's not right. Since transactions are orthogonal to batches, you can of course easily start a transaction and later attempt to perform an action that you do not have permissions for, since the server isn't capable of predicting the future.